# How to compose properly timer Observables in ReactiveX?

Tags: rx-java, rx-android

The method `startPositionInfoPolling` executes polling every 2 seconds of the `PositionInfo` from a remote side and updating the UI.

```
private Subscription mPollingTimerSubscription;
private Observable<Long> mPollingTimerObservable = Observable.timer(0, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

private void startPositionInfoPolling() {
    LOGGER.trace("...");
    mPollingTimerSubscription = mPollingTimerObservable
            .flatMap(new Func1<Long, Observable<PositionInfo>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<PositionInfo> call(Long ticker) {
                    LOGGER.debug("XXX ticker = {}", ticker);
                    return mMediaRendererClient.createPositionInfoObservable();
                }
            })
            .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Action1<PositionInfo>() {
                @Override
                public void call(final PositionInfo positionInfo) {
                    LOGGER.debug("XXX positionInfo = {}", positionInfo);
                    mMusicMediaTrackDetailsFragment.updateView(updatedPositionInfo);
                }
            });
}
```

The method `stopPositionInfoPolling` stops the UI updates.

```
private void stopPositionInfoPolling() {
    LOGGER.trace("...");
    mPollingTimerSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

I would like to change the code so that it less periodically (e.g. every 20s) fetches remote data and periodically (e.g. every 1s) updates the UI with an extrapolated value.

My first solution using RxJava looked like:

```
private Subscription mPollingTimerSubscription, mUpdatingTimerSubscription;
private Observable<Long> mPollingTimerObservable = Observable.timer(0, 20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
private Observable<Long> mUpdatingTimerObservable = Observable.timer(0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

private void startPositionInfoPolling() {
    LOGGER.trace("...");
    mPollingTimerSubscription = mPollingTimerObservable
            .subscribe(new Action1<Long>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Long ticker) {
                    LOGGER.debug("XXX ticker = {}", ticker);
                    mMediaRendererClient.createPositionInfoObservable()
                            .retry(2)
                            .subscribe(new Action1<PositionInfo>() {
                                @Override
                                public void call(final PositionInfo positionInfo) {
                                    LOGGER.debug("XXX positionInfo = {}", positionInfo);
                                    mUpdatingTimerSubscription = mUpdatingTimerObservable
                                            .take(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                                            .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                                            .subscribe(new Action1<Long>() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void call(Long ticker) {
                                                    LOGGER.debug("XXX ticker = {}", ticker);
                                                    String updatedRelTime = ModelUtil.toTimeString(ModelUtil.fromTimeString(positionInfo.getRelTime()) + ticker);
                                                    PositionInfo updatedPositionInfo = new PositionInfo(positionInfo, updatedRelTime, positionInfo.getAbsTime());
                                                    LOGGER.debug("XXX positionInfo = {}", updatedPositionInfo);
                                                    mMusicMediaTrackDetailsFragment.updateView(updatedPositionInfo);
                                                }
                                            });
                                }
                            });
                }
            });
}

private void stopPositionInfoPolling() {
    LOGGER.trace("...");
    mPollingTimerSubscription.unsubscribe();
    mUpdatingTimerSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Could someone help me with transforming this code into something less callback looking like?! I feel `flatMap` is the key, but my mind is still not thinking reactively ;-)

Also a problem is that `mPollingTimerSubscription.unsubscribe();` is not unsubscribing/cancelling/stopping the `mUpdatingTimerObservable`, so another subscription is being maintained.

Thanks in advance for any comments.

**UPDATE:** Thanks @hello_world for reducing the original complexity ;-)

```
private Subscription mPollingTimerSubscription, mUpdatingTimerSubscription;
private Observable<Long> mPollingTimerObservable = Observable.timer(0, 20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
private Observable<Long> mUpdatingTimerObservable = Observable.timer(0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

private void startPositionInfoPolling() {
    LOGGER.trace("...");
    mPollingTimerSubscription = mPollingTimerObservable
            .flatMap(new Func1<Long, Observable<PositionInfo>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<PositionInfo> call(Long ticker) {
                    LOGGER.debug("XXX ticker = {}", ticker);
                    return mMediaRendererClient.createPositionInfoObservable();
                }
            })
            .retry(2)
            .subscribe(new Action1<PositionInfo>() {
                @Override
                public void call(final PositionInfo positionInfo) {
                    LOGGER.debug("XXX positionInfo = {}", positionInfo);
                    mUpdatingTimerSubscription = mUpdatingTimerObservable
                            .take(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                            .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                            .subscribe(new Action1<Long>() {
                                @Override
                                public void call(Long ticker) {
                                    LOGGER.debug("XXX ticker = {}", ticker);
                                    String updatedRelTime = ModelUtil.toTimeString(ModelUtil.fromTimeString(positionInfo.getRelTime()) + ticker);
                                    PositionInfo updatedPositionInfo = new PositionInfo(positionInfo, updatedRelTime, positionInfo.getAbsTime());
                                    LOGGER.debug("XXX positionInfo = {}", updatedPositionInfo);
                                    mMusicMediaTrackDetailsFragment.updateView(updatedPositionInfo);
                                }
                            });
                }
            });
}

private void stopPositionInfoPolling() {
    LOGGER.trace("...");
    mPollingTimerSubscription.unsubscribe();
    mUpdatingTimerSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment, so I'll just post an answer.

Why don't you try using the timer operator?

```
Observable
    .timer(delay, interval, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .subscribe(/*  ...  */);
```

Also, you have a few other variants of timer to use.

Maybe these will help -

- [Learning RxJava (for Android) by example](https://newcircle.com/s/post/1744/2015/06/29/learning-rxjava-for-android-by-example) Checkout the slides around the middle. He shows how to use a timer.
- [Timer](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/timer.html)

Try this code:

```
mPollingTimerObservable
    .flatMap(new Func1<Long, Observable<PositionInfo>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<PositionInfo> call(Long Long) {
            LOGGER.debug("XXX ticker = {}", ticker);
            return mMediaRendererClient.createPositionInfoObservable();
        }
    })
    .retry(2)
    .subscribe(new Action1<PositionInfo>() {
        @Override
        public void call(final PositionInfo positionInfo) {
            LOGGER.debug("XXX positionInfo = {}", positionInfo);
            mUpdatingTimerSubscription = mUpdatingTimerObservable
                .take(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Action1<Long>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(Long ticker) {
                        LOGGER.debug("XXX ticker = {}", ticker);
                        String updatedRelTime = ModelUtil.toTimeString(ModelUtil.fromTimeString(positionInfo.getRelTime()) + ticker);
                        PositionInfo updatedPositionInfo = new PositionInfo(positionInfo, updatedRelTime, positionInfo.getAbsTime());
                        LOGGER.debug("XXX positionInfo = {}", updatedPositionInfo);
                        mMusicMediaTrackDetailsFragment.updateView(updatedPositionInfo);
                    }
                });
        }
    });
```

**UPDATE**

I've thought of a way to make it simple. I had the whole zip concept wrong. :P
My bad! Anyway, here is a new 'flattened' code

```
mPollingTimerObservable
    .flatMap(new Func1<Long, Observable<PositionInfo>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<PositionInfo> call(Long Long) {
            LOGGER.debug("XXX ticker = {}", ticker);
            return mMediaRendererClient.createPositionInfoObservable();
        }
    })
    .retry(2)
    .zipWith(mUpdatingTimerObservable, new Func2<PositionInfo, Long, PositionInfo>() {
            @Override
            public PositionInfo call(PositionInfo p, Long l) {
                return p;
            }
        })
    .take(20)
    .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(/* ... */);
```

I haven't had time to test this, but I think it should work.
Do let me know if it does not!

Comment: Obviously is my question not clear enough. I am already using `Observable.timer` (even twice). The problem is in a composition.

Comment: oh.. sorry dint notice that! I had just glanced through the question actually. my bad.

Comment: just added the flatmap you wanted! im not sure if it will do the trick, but it is worth the try. and i cant add another flat map as the positioninfo object will be lost if i put a flatmap between the retry and second time. but will see what i can do

Comment: and use compositesubscription, it should solve the subscription related problems. let me know if you still have the same problem. here - http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/subscriptions/CompositeSubscription.html

Comment: Thanks for your help. I wonder if it is possible to further "flatten" the code.

Comment: i dont think you can. caz the retry returns a stream of position info and the second time, a stream of long. you would have to destroy the stream to make a time, which you cant caz you need the position info later. If you want to fatten it, youll have to create a new object with position info and long as members and zip the two streams.

Comment: what do you think about the idea to combine the update stream (every sec) with the less frequent stream of `PositionInfo` (which can be `retry`-ed) and use `timestamp` info to extrapolate?!

Comment: I'll see if I can do something on this.. Ill post something by the end of the day.

Answer (score 0):

After some discussion with @hello_world and a bit of thinking, the combined observable of two timestamped observable seems to do the job.
Very powerful concept indeed, but a bit of ugly code thanks to Java syntax.

```
private Subscription mPollingAndUpdatingTimerSubscription;
private Observable<Long> mPollingTimerObservable = Observable.timer(0, 20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
private Observable<Long> mUpdatingTimerObservable = Observable.timer(0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

private void startPositionInfoPolling() {
    LOGGER.trace("...");
    Observable<Timestamped<PositionInfo>> timestampedPositionInfoObservable =
            mPollingTimerObservable
                    .flatMap(new Func1<Long, Observable<PositionInfo>>() {
                        @Override
                        public Observable<PositionInfo> call(Long ticker) {
                            LOGGER.debug("XXX ticker = {}", ticker);
                            return mMediaRendererClient.createPositionInfoObservable();
                        }
                    })
                    .retry()
                    .timestamp();
    Observable<Timestamped<Long>> timestampedUpdateObservable = mUpdatingTimerObservable.timestamp();
    Observable<PositionInfo> combinedPositionInfoObservable = Observable.combineLatest(
            timestampedPositionInfoObservable,
            timestampedUpdateObservable,
            new Func2<Timestamped<PositionInfo>, Timestamped<Long>, PositionInfo>() {
                @Override
                public PositionInfo call(Timestamped<PositionInfo> timestampedPositionInfo, Timestamped<Long> timestampedUpdate) {
                    PositionInfo orgPositionInfo = timestampedPositionInfo.getValue();
                    long delayInMillis = timestampedUpdate.getTimestampMillis() - timestampedPositionInfo.getTimestampMillis();
                    LOGGER.debug("XXX delayInMillis = {}", delayInMillis);
                    String updatedRelTime = DurationUtil.format(DurationUtil.parse(orgPositionInfo.getRelTime()).getTime() + delayInMillis);
                    return new PositionInfo(orgPositionInfo, updatedRelTime, orgPositionInfo.getAbsTime());
                }
            });
    mPollingAndUpdatingTimerSubscription =
            combinedPositionInfoObservable
                    .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(new Action1<PositionInfo>() {
                        @Override
                        public void call(final PositionInfo positionInfo) {
                            LOGGER.debug("XXX positionInfo = {}", positionInfo);
                            mMusicMediaTrackDetailsFragment.updateView(positionInfo);
                        }
                    });
}

private void stopPositionInfoPolling() {
    LOGGER.trace("...");
    mPollingAndUpdatingTimerSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Comment: holy mother of lord! :O